# searchResultsTableView displays two of same cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a search bar that pulls data from a Parse server. I have noticed that sometimes the tableView will display double of the same cell while I am typing.

[image]
[image]

If I continue to type the it will then only display one of the cells. I have noticed that if I type slowly only one cell displays the entire time (as it should). Perhaps the Parse queries are coming back too fast for the tableView to reload properly?

Any light that you guys could shed on this issue would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

**EDIT**

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
[self.searchResult removeAllObjects];
[self.queryArray removeAllObjects];

NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchText];

PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"fullName" containsString:searchText];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        for (PFObject *pfObj in objects)
        {
            NSDictionary *person = [[NSDictionary alloc]
                                    initWithObjects:@[pfObj[@"fullName"], pfObj.objectId]
                                    forKeys:@[@"name", @"objectId"]];
            [self.queryArray addObject:person];
        }

        self.searchResult = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [self.contacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate]];
        [self.searchResult addObjectsFromArray:self.queryArray];
        NSLog(@"query array %@", self.queryArray);
        NSLog(@"%@", self.searchResult);
        [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }
}];
[self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Are you making two separate array for searching ?

Comment: plz share your search code

Comment: I have updated my post with my filterContentForSearchText. Is there anything else you would like to see? @PallaviLigade

Comment: Can you use simple loop instead of backgroundblock .. Rest of ur code is correct

Comment: I have to use background block because Parse will throw errors otherwise

Comment: Are you able to solve problem?

Comment: I was not able to solve the problem yet. @PallaviLigade

Comment: Is that possible for u to upload ur project POC code of this task on git. So I can check practically if u don't mind.

Comment: Also have the same problem @TylerRiedal .. Have you found a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Make your array nil while you are changing the text field Value. What I mean to say every time you type its going to call a function in which you will get sorted array of values. So before calling it make it nil.  Because it stores the data from previous search as well and that's why you get same data twice. I had this same Problem and it took me hell of a time to figure this out :D

Comment: My code clears the arrays at the beginning of the block but the problem still persists :/

Comment: Is it just happening with one specific name or with every other name?. If it's with specific name then it might be possible that's it's because the data that you are getting contains the name "Joe Smith" twice

Comment: It happens with every single name