# tableView showing same cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform, pfquery

I'm making an social application in which I want to display the comments from the users. 
Now sometimes when I open the VC it will display the same cell twice (or sometimes even more). See the picture below:

[image: Storyboard and Realtime]

The strange thing is when I 'println' the objects from the 'PFQuery Block' in the `CellForRowAtIndexPath` it shows the println 2 times or more. I have no idea how this comes.. Something to do with CachePolicy maybe?

P.s: No answer found at same problem: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28272232/searchresultstableview-displays-two-of-same-cell)

```
}else {
        let commentCell:commentTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("commentCell") as commentTableViewCell

        let commentIndex:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row-2, inSection: 0)
        let comment:PFObject = userComments.objectAtIndex(commentIndex.row) as PFObject

        // Comment Label
        commentCell.commentLabel.text = comment.objectForKey("content") as String!

        // Datum
        let date:NSDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1)
        let string:NSString = date.timeAgoSinceDate(comment.createdAt)
        commentCell.datumLabel.text = string

        // Load each comment after row: 1
        var userCommentImage:PFQuery = PFUser.query()
        userCommentImage.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: comment.objectForKey("gebruiker").objectId)
        userCommentImage.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
            (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil{

                println("How many reactions are there? = \(objects.count)")

                let user:PFUser = (objects as NSArray).firstObject as PFUser
                commentCell.userLabel.text = user.username

                // Profile Image
                let profileImage:PFFile = user["profileImage"] as PFFile
                profileImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
                    (imageData:NSData!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
                    if error == nil{
                        let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                        commentCell.userImageView.image = image

                        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
                            commentCell.userImageView.alpha = 1
                            commentCell.userLabel.alpha = 1
                            commentCell.datumLabel.alpha = 1
                            commentCell.commentLabel.alpha = 1
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        })

        return commentCell
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked the datasource to make sure the objects you are using to populate your tableViewCells are not duplicates?  You should try setting a breakpoint where you set comment, and then interrogate the objects to see if they contain the same data values or not.

Comment: Where is this code executed?

Comment: @soulshined `CellForRowAtIndex`.